# Android SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, json, sqlite, aes, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to implement a script and I dont understand how it connect to the database and encrypt/decrypt the playlist stream from the the database server  using SQLiteDatabase or paramSQLiteDatabase and play the video file.

I hardly understand how, I have tested the apk and its working good using the example I've also changed the link for the m3u that is Json and everything is working but I cannot play my own streams since they are not encrypted or I maybe wrong but I am stuck at seeing where is the database file or php that create user or connect to the mysql, its using AES encrypt and I dont know how.

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
  {
    paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE video(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(20), image varchar(40) NULL, vodid  varchar(10) NULL, queue varchar(20) NULL, category integer DEFAULT 1)");
    paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tv(_id integer primary key autoincrement, idTv integer DEFAULT 1 , logo varchar(50) null, mode integer DEFAULT 1, name varchar(20), playUrl varchar(50) null, sort integr DEFAULT 1, typeId integer DEFAULT 1)");
    paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE lock(_id integer primary key autoincrement, idTv integer DEFAULT 1 , logo varchar(50) null, mode integer DEFAULT 1, name varchar(20), playUrl varchar(50) null, sort integr DEFAULT 1, typeId integer DEFAULT 1)");
  }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
  }
```

Here is the source from  [github](https://github.com/AresMobile1484/Android_IPTV/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/redorange/motutv1)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the question itself. We're not going to download the whole app

Comment: I am so sorry, I am not asking anyone to download the whole app but rather look at the script since I am not sure if which page I need to show. I have edited my question and added the android line where is ask for database create

Comment: How do you know the app requires PHP or MySQL?

Comment: Not sure but when I opened the html page that is in ChannelParser.java ( http://extremeiptv.com:8080//channel/stb/checkTermOfValidity.htm?str= ) ity looks like is writen with php to connect to the database but this is just me as I said I'am a total fresh to android, Ihave went through all example and I cant find how also even if i creat a php to do this , how did he ecrypted is that example.

Comment: You can't simply "inspect" a webpage and determine if it's in PHP. `.htm` file extension probably is not PHP, though.

Comment: Yeah it can be json or anything but how to use my own streams? and where is it getting the LoginInforParser data from? Many thanks

Comment: I have used the same streams in the example using my own link and its working but when i use my stream or any format that is written to mp4 or ts etc it wont play as it uses AESUtil.decrypt, Hard for beginner to understand without help.

Comment: Hi cricket_007 My question in short is how to use my own database (vod.db) and where to change the url for that db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141692/discussion-between-altin-bana-and-cricket-007).

Comment: `vod.db` is a **SQLite** database file **within** the application. There is no visible MySQL here

Comment: Many thanks cricket_007 just noticed that after going through and google around a lot that its writable database that is saved inside the app somewhere secure. I'am still searching to know how the PlayURL inside Json example file is encrypted and decrypt using AESUtil.decrypt(paramChannel.getPlayUrl())).

Comment: And here is how the url link to the video look like any help please?
 (playUrl":"xOBBqqDUD22AxvC8lcn4jat5hl0iz87pJfMKONOCxq4cTBLAwZjNwMScoSphs7uqIVWUQ1XnsITb\n7jxKqHMiSuSp869D+7cVOgHiu945oYsFuy9QnUpRCpyS/s0vD3X2DNPavmxv+fWdg1dZc57X/6XR\nzU7w4c7NB5jJcUl+djjYKqBlsHQ0hh5ghwAPXyOAc4ca3eFOhXofQKWruAvCrdB1dOEVhnrW0TiF\nCDobtJYHPAQwPi/lCl19aMqATwOT")

Comment: I have no idea. How about you set a breakpoint when debugging the code?

Comment: Yeah I will try if that is easy for an android leaner like me. Thanks